# Chose icon in google map as Marker

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, android-drawable

This is my code and it compiles correctly, but when I want to run the app, it shows

> Unfortunately, app has stopped

This is my code:

```
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map = googleMap;
        LatLng pp = new LatLng( 12,12 );
        MarkerOptions option = new MarkerOptions();
        option.position(pp)
                .title( "hi " )
                .snippet("for test");

        option.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.about));

        map.addMarker( option );
        map.moveCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng( pp ) );
```

When I remove this line:

```
option.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.about));
```

it works correctly. I need to change default marker but I can't.

Comment: can you share you logcat output?

Comment: log file may be png is too big.

Comment: If the BitmapDesriptorFactory is failed to load the image, the BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.about) would return null. Due to some reason the image is not getting loaded. If you can provide log, it would be helpful

Comment: I dont know how can use log for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change default marker with color in google map, please try below like this:

```
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(BROOKLYN_BRIDGE)
        .title("First Pit Stop")
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));
```

Comment: @ Blackkara its optional.

Comment: I alwayse use

 .icon( BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.busstation) );

but now it dosent work.

Comment: i copied several image in drawable folder.one of them was about.png.
i copied another imame and it work.i dont know why the previous image dont work....>   .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
        .fromResource(R.drawable.my_flag)) . is the answer.

Comment: i copied about.png in drawable folder but (v21) is beside of its name.